# Call different functions based on *ngIf in angular 4

Tags: angular, function, angular-ng-if

I am new to Angular 4. Am trying to delete a group created in DB with webservice. If the group holds any users, then I have to give a warning message to user. If the group is empty, I can delete it. 
For warning message , I have used bootstrap modal and for deleting am having Angular function(**deleteGroup(group)**) which will call web service in turn to delete the group.

Based on the usercount in that group, I tried to use *ngIf, but failed. Can someone help me to sort it out?

**Function flow:**

```
1) Groups are listed in drop-down and the user chooses the one
2)Clicking on delete button, calls the getUsers() funtion to check
the availability of users in that group (group members count is
assidgned to usersCount variable )
3) Based on the usersCount, next step has to be done
   a) usersCount == 0 , => delete the group   
   b) usersCount !=0 , => pop-up warning message
```

**HTML code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
     (click)="getUsers(optionSelected)" >Delete</button> //getuser function gets  the number of users in that group
     <div *ngIf="usersCount ==0 ">deleteGroup(optionSelected)</div> //usercount -> number of users
</button>
```

Typescript code:

```
getUsers(value): void {
    this.output = [];
    this.textValue.getUsers(value)
        .subscribe(res => {
                this.output = res;
                this.usersCount = this.output.length;
                console.log ("Number of users:", this.usersCount);
         })
}
```

Comment: Add typescript code as well. what  does **usercount** print in console?

Comment: Added the typescript code for your reference. Userscount variable holds the number of users in that group.

Answer (score 1):

That's usually a bad idea.

HTML templates are being parsed & checked several times during the application lifecycle.

If you write what you did, your function will be called 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 times and will result in erratic behaviors.

Instead, you should delete the group *on request* : if the user clicks, navigate ... The best would to be to post all of you code and explain your end goal. I'll make an edit to my answer once you've done it.

#### EDIT

From your comment, you should have a dropdown with a delete button, and this button should be like this :

```
<button *ngIf="!usercount" (click)="deleteGroup(optionSelected)">Delete group</button>
```

(Based on the code of your own button)

Now, the user only has to click on this button, and the function will be called, deleting the user group. The button will not be shown if the user count is falsy (meaning "equal to zero" in your case), meaning the user can't click on it.

Comment: your are correct. function is being called in infinite loop and making the system to hang. I have added the typescript code.

Comment: Could you also explain your workflow in your question ? "When my user [clicks | change page | ...], I want to [delete] then [display result | reroute] ..."

Comment: Edited the question as per your suggestion

Comment: :D Not really what I wanted to read. I already know you're using *ngIf. What I want to know is what would the user do to delete groups. I want you to explain as if you were the user, and if you had no knowledge about Javascript or Angular. This way, I could explain to you how to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: User clicks the 'Delete Group' button; It lists all the available groups in the drop-down; User chooses the group from it and clicks on 'Delete' button.

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche for your answer; But still part of my requirement is missing. Pop-up warning message if the group has users?

Comment: @Raji I don't have enough information about your CSS framework to do that, but since the user can't click on the button if there is more than one user, you should not need that pop-up. This leaves you two options : always show the button and pop-up when there is a group, or don't show the button when there is a group.